# symfony prod still dev

Tags: php, symfony, deployment, production

I'm new at Symfony 2.8 and I can't seem to get my dev in production mode.

Allthough I ran the following commands:

**to create the assets**

```
php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
```

**to clear the cache**

```
php app/console --env=prod cache:clear
```

**to warm up the cache**

```
php app/console cache:warmup --env=prod --no-debug
```

If I'm right (which I'm probably not because it's not working) that should be it.

I've even tried setting `$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);` to `$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);` in app.php. But that didn't help either.

This production app runs on Ubuntu 14.04 with apache2 and php 5.5

Any help on this matter would be great.

Comment: what's the problem? why do you say that you're still in `dev` env?

Comment: When I go to my test page it still says welcome to 2.8.4_Dev instead of Prod

Comment: This page can be found on [link](http://admin.elofan.be/). Which is actually a copy of the default index.html.twig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im guessing you must have this deployed on a server, rather than your local machine. `app_dev.php` won't run on a production server, by design. You can modify it, by adding your own IP address though, and then it will run.

Anyway, I've had this problem too. You're not actually in `debug` mode. It's just that something must have gone wrong in Symfony's build process because their stable versions are being suffixed by `-DEV`.

Check out the file`Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php` in the `vendors` directory. Look for `const VERSION`. It's value is probably like `x.x.x-DEV`.

Comment: The file `Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php` wasn't found but doing a search on my local machine pointed me to the direction of Bootstrap.php.cache. So I looked it up on my remote server and the const VERSION is set to `x.x.x-DEV` in this file. I changed it to `x.x.x-prod` and now it shows I'm on production. Hopefully this did the trick. Is there a check I can run to be absolutely certain that I'm on production?

Comment: You should read this document about [Symfony environments](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/cookbook/configuration/environments.html). Changing the value of `VERSION` doesn't change the actual environment, it's only a representational value. You can just ignore it.The environment is set by the front controllers, `app_dev.php` and `app.php`. You don't need to run a check to see which one you're in, you can just presume that if you run your application from `app_dev` you're in `dev` and `app.php` you're in `prod`.

Answer (score 0):

2 things:

First you missed the right command:

```
php app/console assets:install --env=prod --no-debug
```

now it should work :)

2nd, in your url you access production env like this:

http://whatever/app.php

not

http://whatever/app_dev.php

Comment: I tried the first command and still it says Welcome to Symfony 2.8.4 dev. If I add app.php to it it autoremoves that from the url. If I add app_dev I'm given **You are not allowed to access this file. Check app_dev.php for more information.**